# What's the difference between /usr/include/linux and the include folder in linux kernel source?

Tags: linux, include, linux-kernel

On a freshly installed Ubuntu , i found kernel headers in both `/usr/include/linux` , and `/usr/src/kernel-version-headers/include/linux`

Are they mutually the same ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are very different; the `/usr/include/linux` headers are the headers that were used when compiling the system's standard C library. They are owned by the C library packaging, and updated in lockstep with the standard C library. They exist to provide the *userland* interface to the kernel, as understood and "brokered"<sup>1</sup> by the C library.

The `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux` headers are used via the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` symbolic links. They are owned by the kernel headers packages and updated in lockstep with the kernel. These are a *subset* of the kernel headers and enough of the Kbuild system required to build out-of-tree kernel modules. These files represent the *kernel internals* -- modules must build against these if they are to properly understand in-memory objects. See the kernel's `Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` file for some details.

---

1: "Mediated" was my first word choice, but it implies some sort of access controls, which isn't the case. "Brokered" implies a third-party process, but that is also not the case. Consider: when a C program calls `_exit()`, it is actually calling the Standard C library's `_exit()` *wrapper*, which calls the `exit(2)` system call. The `select(2)` interface has an upper limit on the number of file descriptors that can be tracked, and that limit is compiled into the standard C library. Even if the kernel's interface were extended, the C library would also need to be recompiled.